# Gremlin Graph API query logging

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Using Gremlin Graph API to connect Azure Cosmos DB.

It is possible to log each query executing using Gremlin API to App Insight or some blob ?

Objective is to find out what query are running and what is their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can create a client and made the connection. Each time you pass the query write a logger to appInishgts.

Whatever information you need to write to AppInsights can be logged. On the execute method once the results have been got you can add the time.

Comment: Thanks Sajeet. Graph API is Rest API call. It must be writing all request to Log Analytics. If it write all request to Log Analytics then I can set it to export to Blob storage.